# (Logical Indexing) Executing formula for RGBA values in numpy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, indexing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to unpremultiply my png image by accessing values via logical indexing. Made it work in python for loop before but I can't get it done right by using logical indexing. (for loop takes up to 1 minute)

Getting my image in numpy array

```
img = Image.open('test.png')
matrix = numpy.array(img)
```

Changing values using common for loops

```
for line in matrix:
   for v in line:
       if v[3]:
           v[0] = (255 * v[0] + (v[3] / 2)) / v[3]
           v[1] = (255 * v[1] + (v[3] / 2)) / v[3]
           v[2] = (255 * v[2] + (v[3] / 2)) / v[3]
```

It ended up looking like this using logical indexing

```
height, width, depth = matrix.shape
r = matrix[0:height, 0:width//4, 0:1]
g = matrix[0:height, 0:width//4, 1:2]
b = matrix[0:height, 0:width//4, 2:3]
a = matrix[0:height, 0:width//4, 3:4]

matrix[0:height, 0:width//4, 0:1] = (255 * r + (a / 2)) / a
matrix[0:height, 0:width//4, 1:2] = (255 * g + (a / 2)) / a
matrix[0:height, 0:width//4, 2:3] = (255 * b + (a / 2)) / a
```

How do I change the desired values correctly?
If there is a better than doing it with logical indexing, please enlighten me.

EDIT: Added example images

test.png
[image: test.png]

what it looks like with for loop (desired result)
[image: test_unpm.png]

what it looks like using indexing
[image]

Comment: Are those loopy and using logical index. based ones supposed to achieve the same thing? You have `0:width//4` for the latter, causing confusion.

Comment: why do you only index until `width//4`? You don't seem to do that in the `for` loop.

Comment: @ThomasKühn To get 4 values (RGBA). Is it used the wrong way?

Comment: well, you have the depth as separate index. how does `matrix.shape` look like?

Comment: those are the values of matrix.shape (2480, 3508, 4)

Comment: Is the loop code giving you the expected values?

Comment: Yes it does. It's correctly unpremultiplying my PNG image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
matrix_out = matrix.astype(float)
vals = (255 * matrix_out[...,:3] + matrix_out[...,[3]]/2)/matrix_out[...,[3]]
mask = matrix[...,3]!=0
matrix[mask,:3] = vals[mask]
```

Thus, the updated values would be in `matrix`.

Comment: The image ends up being completely transparent using your code.
Multiplying with "matrix" includes the alpha value too but only rgb needs to get changed.

Comment: Just tried it out now. It's giving me the same result as my approach using indexing does. Refer to the images  I just add to see what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: values difference from for loop and indexing looks like this:
for loop   [102 102 102 255]
indexing  [  0   0   0 255]

Comment: @SHooDK As noted in other post, seems like dtype was causing the issue. Check out the edits again.

Comment: thanks. the dtype was the problem it seems. changed "float" to "np.float" and made it a few milliseconds faster too.

Comment: @SHooDK Check out tthe edits made with focus on improving performance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, this should do the job:

```
r = matrix[:,:,0]
g = matrix[:,:,1]
b = matrix[:,:,2]
a = matrix[:,:,3]

r[a>0] = ((255*r + (a/2))/a)[a>0]
g[a>0] = ((255*g + (a/2))/a)[a>0]
b[a>0] = ((255*b + (a/2))/a)[a>0]
```

**EDIT**:

This must be because of the `dtype` of your matrix. If you first change your matrix to `float` values, it should work:

```
matrix2 = matrix.astype(np.float)

r = matrix2[:,:,0]
g = matrix2[:,:,1]
b = matrix2[:,:,2]
a = matrix2[:,:,3]

r[a>0] = ((255*r + (a/2))/a)[a>0]
g[a>0] = ((255*g + (a/2))/a)[a>0]
b[a>0] = ((255*b + (a/2))/a)[a>0]

matrix_out = matrix2.astype(np.uint8)
```

The final result can then be found in `matrix_out`.

Comment: your code gives me the same result as my current code using indexing but it's made simpler though. check out the example images I just added. Maybe it helps to see what I want to achieve.